# Why can't I call this.state in my redux reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I made a reducer that fetches admins, and I want it to display certain admins when I call it in my reducer but I am getting Undefined.

I am still very new to redux so apologies for my mistakes.
I tried to include all the relevant folders:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../store/actions';

class App extends Component {

  async componentDidMount() {

    fetch(constants.adminUrl + '/admins/data', {
      method: 'GET'
    }).then((res) => {
      return res.json()
    }).then(async (res) => {
      this.props.setAdminsInColumns(res.admins)
    }).catch((error) => {
      toast.error(error.message)
    })
  }


  render() {
    return (
        {/* SOME CODE */}
    );
  }
}

let app = connect(null, actions)(App);
export default app;
```

**columnsReducer.js**

```
import { FETCH_ADMINS } from '../actions/types'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import constants from '../../static/global/index'
import React from 'react';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify'

const initialState = {
  admins: [],
{
      Header: "Responsible",
      accessor: "responsibleAdmin",
      style: { textAlign: "center" },
//  Place where I want to fetch certain admins and get undefined
      Cell: props => <span>{props.value && this.state.admins.name ? this.state.admins.find(admin => admin.id === props.value).name : props.value}</span>
    }
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_ADMINS:
      return { ...state, admins: action.admins}
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import { FETCH_ADMINS } from "./types"

/**
* starts loader for setting admin
*/

export const setAdminsInColumns = (admins) => async dispatch => {
 dispatch({ type: FETCH_ADMINS, admins })
}
```

**types.js**

`export const FETCH_ADMINS = 'fetch_admins'`

When I `console.log(action.admins)` inside the switch case FETCH_ADMINS in the columnsReducer.js file, I can see all the admin information I want, is there a way to make the state global in the columnsReducer.js file so I can read it?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

use mapStateToProps in the connect method. like below

```
let mapStateToProps = (state)=>{
 return {
    admins :[yourcolumnsReducer].admins
 }
}
let app = connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(App);
```

//you can use this.props.admins inside your component

[MapStateToProps reference](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate)

Comment: @satishkumar you are not passing `mapStateToProps` as the first argument of `connect`.